# Casting a MongoDB document to a strongly typed class

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Can anyone tell me how to cast a document retrieved from MongoDB to a class I have created myself? I don't want to use Mongoose, I am using github.com/christkv/mongodb-legacy v2.0.13

The values of the document returned from MongoDB

```
{
    id { MongoDb ID},
    email: 'me@home.com',
    passwordHash: '$2a$04$Wjan4CloaZRYj60MGsDb6e7x11e1QYkjW3N2q5JYBDaKBNipLti36',
    passwordSalt: '$2a$04$Wjan4CloaZRYj60MGsDb6e',
    id: 'mrpmorris'
}
```

The code that is failing to execute

```
var user = Object.create(User.prototype, document)
```

The exception thrown

```
TypeError: Property description must be an object: $2a$04$Wjan4CloaZRYj60MGsDb6e
    at defineProperties (native)
    at Function.create (native)
```

The User class

```
var assert = require('assert')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var User = (function () {
    function User() {
        this.passwordSalt = "hello"
    }

    User.prototype.constructor = User
    User.prototype.setPassword = function (newPassword, callback) {
        var self = this
        assert.ok(newPassword != null, "newPassword cannot be null")
        assert.ok(newPassword.length >= 8)
        bcrypt.genSalt(2, function (err, salt) {
            self.passwordSalt = salt
            bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt, function (err, hash) {
                self.passwordHash = hash
                callback(err);
            })
        });
    }

    User.prototype.checkPassword = function (password, callback) {
        var self = this
        bcrypt.hash(self.passwordHash, self.passwordSalt, function (err, hash) {
            callback(err, hash === self.passwordHash)
        })
    }


    return User
})()

exports.User = User
```

Comment: Why don't you take the user-document as parameter in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error because `Object.create` expects properties descriptor as its second parameter, sth like

```
var doc = {
    email: 'me@home.com',
    passwordHash: '$2a$04$Wjan4CloaZRYj60MGsDb6e7x11e1QYkjW3N2q5JYBDaKBNipLti36',
    passwordSalt: '$2a$04$Wjan4CloaZRYj60MGsDb6e',
    id: 'mrpmorris'
};

var user = Object.create(User.prototype, {
    // regular 'value property'
    email:        { writable: true, configurable: true, value: doc.email        },
    passwordHash: { writable: true, configurable: true, value: doc.passwordHash },
    passwordSalt: { writable: true, configurable: true, value: doc.passwordSalt },
    id:           { writable: true, configurable: true, value: doc.id           }
});
```

Please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Example:_Using_propertiesObject_argument_with_Object.create) for details

Alternatively, as @cbass suggested, you may pass mongo document object to `User` constructor

```
function User(doc) {
    this.id = doc.id;
    this.email = doc.email;
    this.passwordHash = doc.passwordHash;
    this.passwordSalt = doc.passwordSalt;
}
//...
var user = new User(doc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I've decided instead to de-oop my model and just create functions that perform operations on docs